# Postal address multi-value attribute

Tags: relational-database

new to stackoverflow.

Pretty low level question here I'm sure but I'm designing a relational data model and in several of my tables the case study I'm working from has said that 'postal address' should be stored as an attribute. Not only is this very vague, but surely multi-valued, which the case study states must be resolved. How do I go about splitting this into more specific attributes, baring in mind that of my 5 tables, 3 have at least one address attribute (e.g. correspondence address, term address).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), specifically you need to bring it into the [4th normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4NF) to get rid of the multi-valued dependencies.